# Flutter project on android Studio 4.2.1 no database inspector, profiler and emulator window

Tags: flutter, android-studio

**Two months and no answer. Am I the only one having this problem?**
**Yesterday I downloaded and installed Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 on my new laptop (Windows 10 64 bit, i7-8565U) and HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM AGAIN!!**
**Android projects I have all tools, Flutter project missing emulator window, database inspector and profiler!**

Android Studio 4.2.1 on Windows 10. Latest stable Flutter version.
If I create an Android project I have all tools: database inspector, profiler and the emulator window.
If I create a Flutter project I have **no database inspector, no profiler and no emulator window**.
Flutter doctor gives no error.
Everything worked fine until the upgrade to 4.2.1
What's going on? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, basically it doesn't work. That's it. Maybe one day it will. In the meantime I'm using AS 4.1.3 so that I can get all the available tools.

Remember to set `environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` to have null-safety enabled and to go to Project Structure and set an SDK otherwise you'll get the old *ADB.exe file not found* when starting the Emulator which means also no Profiler and a bunch of other tools.

Answer (score 7):

I've had this issue and been following this question from the time you posted it. Finally found a solution to it on another SO question.

> Solution: Enable the Android Facet It turned out that I had to enable
> the Android Facet for this project:
>
> Go to File → Project Structure Choose Facets Press the small + Button
> at the top Select Android from the list Confirm your project by
> clicking the project_name and press OK

Please check out the full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68839489/8362593

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not showing then you can do one thing go to

**Help > Find action or ctrl+shift+A > Then search.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it finds Profile... (Run) no way to activate window. Searching foe Database Inspector finds nothing at all.

Comment: If thats what happening then you didnt build your project right.
First do `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then run your project.

Comment: I did not build anything yet. Just created a new Flutter project. Tried Flutter clean, invalidate cache and restart...same result. The project opens (with the usual main.dart file with the counter sample) and the database inspector, profiler and window emulator are not there. If I then open android>app>build.gradle (in the same project folder) then I get the tools...going back to main.dart makes the disappear again...

Answer (score 0):

Try `Windows -> Restore default` (Shift+F12 by default)

And also you can specify which windows to show: In bookMark `View`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might rather have the `PATH` wrong (which means: using an outdated `emulator`),
because the `emulator` now resides in directory called `emulator` (which wasn't always the case).

This can be easily verified:

```
emulator -v
emulator: Android emulator version 30.8.4.0 (build_id 7600983) (CL:N/A)
```

If you'd get anything less than the current version `30.8.4.0` (despite having installed version  `30.8.4.0` with the SDK Manager), you'd know what the actual cause is. Once having fixed the `PATH`, the proper version of the `emulator` should become accessible / usable ...and even an upgrade to Arctic Fox should then be possible, at least while the Flutter `build.gradle` scripts are compatible with Gradle `7.1.1`.

Comment: PATH is correct and emulator is last version. It wouldn't fix all the other problems anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround in words, you probably found this out, and did not bother to document it.
It is just for the next person :-).

Start your  flutter app in debug mode.

Select your android folder in flutter project.

Right click -> Flutter -> Open in Android Studio.

Do NO upgrade Gradle Plugin, when suggested.
It might break flutter build and is not needed.

Android Window:
Click Debug Icon.
Wait a bit.

Click something in your app, so your db is active.

Android Window:
Click App Inspection at bottom of android window.

Result:
The Database Inspector shows up, and you can inspect db content in android window.

-- You have to switch between  windows, and yes, it is a pain in the but.

-- Flutter plugin and Android integration is lackluster since 2018, but probably very hard to keep up with all that upstream in sync :-(.